# Dialogflow version failed flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to add dialogflow in the flutter application, but it shows error message: "Because flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3 depends on http ^0.12.0+2 which depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0, flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3 requires http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0.
And because firebase_auth_web 1.3.1 depends on http_parser ^4.0.0 and no versions of firebase_auth_web match >1.3.1 <2.0.0, flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3 is incompatible with firebase_auth_web ^1.3.1.
And because firebase_auth 1.4.1 depends on firebase_auth_web ^1.3.1 and no versions of firebase_auth match >1.4.1 <2.0.0, flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3 is incompatible with firebase_auth ^1.4.1.
So, because monger_app depends on both firebase_auth ^1.4.1 and flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because monger_app depends on both firebase_auth ^1.4.1 and flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3, version solving failed.)" I have updated all the dependencies but still got error. Anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my dependencies code

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  #http: ^0.13.3

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_rounded_date_picker: ^2.0.2

  intl: ^0.17.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3

  dropdownfield: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  flutter_dialogflow: ^0.1.3
  #firebase_core: ^1.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  page_transition: ^2.0.2
  animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^0.3.2
  fl_chart: ^0.36.1
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the version numbers of all conflicting dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml` file to `any` and run `flutter pub get`. Flutter will automatically resolve the correct dependency versions.

You can then go to your `pubspec.lock` file and take each specific version and copy it inside `pubspec.yaml` next to each dependency name.